# Routing back to index ( / )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have come across a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I am doing a project in laravel 4, and I have a form to handle navigation between different pages. It routes perfectly between all pages I got there, except when I try to click on the one that would return in to the index file.

Attempting to do so promts me with a NotFoundHTTPException.

The navigation:

```
    <td><form action="/" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="ht" value="Hver time" /></form></td>
    <td><form action="hverdag" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="hd" value="Hver dag" /></form></td>
    <td><form action="hvertirsdag" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="htirs" value="Hver tirsdag" /></form></td>
    <td><form action="kontrollcm" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="kcm" value="Kontroll CM" /></form></td>
    <td><form action="hvertredjetime" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="htt" value="Hver tredje time" /></form></td>
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showIndex'); //Routen for å vise index.php

Route::post('/hverdag', 'HomeController@showHD');

Route::post('/hvertredjetime', 'HomeController@showHTT');

Route::post('/hvertirsdag', 'HomeController@showHTirs');

Route::post('/kontrollcm', 'HomeController@showKontrollcm');
```

aaaand the homecontroller.php:

```
public function showIndex()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

public function showHD()
{
    return View::make('hverdag');
}

public function showHTirs()
{
    return View::make('hvertirsdag');
}

public function showKontrollcm()
{
    return View::make('kontrollcm');
}

public function showHTT()
{
    return View::make('hvertredjetime');
}
```

Also on the exception error page, the URL is the same URL as the working index page, before trying to route to it (I can click the url and just press enter to make it work).
I can't fathom why that exception would be there, thank you for your time guys/gals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@showIndex');
```

to

```
Route::any('/','HomeController@showIndex');
```

or

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@showIndex');
Route::post('/','HomeController@showIndex');
```

because you are using a form with method post, your route should accept post,
and then just to make sure the paths will be correct:
Add the

```
asset();
```

function

```
<td><form action="{{asset('/')}}" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="ht" value="Hver time" /></form></td>
<td><form action="{{asset('hverdag')}}" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="hd" value="Hver dag" /></form></td>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a deeper look of how routes work, what are the methods used in HTTP requests, when to use them, and how to handle them. Keep it up!!